# HTML Entities Encoder in JSP

Tags: html, security, xss, owasp, esapi

I want to use an HTML Entity Encoder for my HTML `<div>${data}</div>`
I was using ESAPI library `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML`  But I am not sure if it is correct, because for instance, the result of encoding **test/a/2** using `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML` is `test&#x2f;a&#x2f;2` (that's what I see in my JSP using :

```
<div><esapi:encodeForHTML>${deviceKey}</esapi:encodeForHTML></div>
```

but on this site http://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder the result is **test/a/2**  (?!)  Why ?

Comment: Both are "correct". Both are equivalent HTML representations of the same string. It's *unnecessary* to encode `/` to `&#x2f;` here, but it's not incorrect either.

Comment: so there is ESAPI encoder equivalent to the other one ? I don't want to encode everything

Comment: Apart from your own aesthetic sensibilities, is there any reason to not want to encode everything? Do you have to use ESAPI for some reason or another? Then just use its HTML encoder, I guess?! You could of course bend over backwards and try alternative ways, but again, what you have is already perfectly "correct".

Comment: well, If I guess the final user would better understand test/a/2, rather than test&#x2f;a&#x2f;2

Comment: So you're saying "test&#x2f;a&#x2f;2" shows up in your UI?

Comment: yes, in my JSP page

Comment: So you're encoding to HTML entities and then apparently use a template which itself encodes to HTML entities?! Then your problem is that you're *double encoding*. If your template already does HTML encoding for you, you don't need to do it with ESAPI as well.

Comment: I just have this in my JSP <esapi:encodeForHTML>${deviceKey}</esapi:encodeForHTML>

Answer (score 0):

ESAPI is almost unsupported due to a lack of interest in maintaining the platform; we'd love to have more active developers.

If you're doing active Ajax replacing of divs, you should look into safe templating and SCE in AngularJS as a replacement for ESAPI.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce